# Order values in a Gridview in ascending order with Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm trying to display ItemName values of 'tblitems' table into a GridView in ascending order. Even I used ascending, it is not order. My main problem is, I cannot understand the code here, since it is already developed system.

```
 public tblItem GetItemByID(int itemID)
        {
            try
            {
                var itm = from u in DB.tblItems
                          where u.ItemID == itemID
                          orderby u.ItemName ascending
                          select u;

                return itm.Single<tblItem>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Please someone help me to understand this code line by line.

Specially cannot understand this line

> return itm.Single();

Comment: What has this method got to do with displaying records in a Gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var itm = from u in DB.tblItems
where u.ItemID == itemID
orderby u.ItemName ascending
select u;
```

This describes that from DB Table tblItems where `ItemId=itemid` and order by `ItemName` in ascending order. Once it is ordered it will return a list which you will select. Always it returns a list. But according to your code it will return a matching item and returns a list of that matching item.

So, the next line `return itm.Single();` returns a single item present in the list.

Comment: Is that mean, this function returns only a single row from the table ?

Comment: Yes. It returns only a single row of type `tblItem` from the table.

Comment: And also this is not arranging in ascending order.. That is the main problem.

Comment: You have to return multiple rows and then try ordering them. You are returning a single row. So you will never know whether the code will order or not.

Comment: If I used,** return itms.ToList<tblItem>();** here,, what will return ?

Comment: It will return all the items in that table ascending ordered by `ItemName`

Comment: Also the return type is a `tblitem`. If you are returning a list make it as `List<tblItem>`

Comment: I got the point. If I need to return a list of values from the table, I can use 'return itms.ToList<tblItem>();' and I should change the heading like this, 'return itms.ToList<tblItem>();' Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. You have to to that.

Comment: This method is called "GetItemByID", note the singular, and returns a single item. It sounds like you shouldn't be using this method at all if you want multiple items, write a new method with a new name. It is also filtering by ItemID, if that is unique you will only get one item back anyway,